# Is there a way to process pull requests in an offline environment?

Tags: git, github, virtual-machine, pull-request

I work on a VM restricted from most internet access. I have code on a shared hard-drive that is accessed by a collaborator. I would like to set up a system where a main repo for production code coexists locally with individual repos for me and my collaborator, where the individual repos can submit pull requests with the main repo. However, I'm not sure how this will work without using the pull request functionality from something like GitHub.

I was able to set up push and pull for the three repos, but am stuck on pull requests.

Comment: A pull request is just a push (to a branch, in some particular clone) and a message asking someone else to pull it. Or some web workflow that does the equivalent. Which bit of that is the problem?

Comment: note that a pull request is *not* part of git itself.  There's no exact equivalent in `git` itself.

Comment: Create a branch on the main repo from the main branch (maybe `main`). Work on that. The “pull request” then becomes asking if you can merge the branch into the main branch. Done?

Answer (score 1):

The "pull request functionality from something like GitHub" is not a Git feature; it is in fact a complete misuse of Git, as implemented by various popular Git hosting sites, such as (as you rightly say) GitHub. Obviously your computer is not GitHub, so what you're asking to do is impossible in that sense.

However, all is not lost. You might be able to do the same sort of thing by, say, installing a GitLab instance locally. Alternatively, you could use the [old-fashioned sense of pull request](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull) which *is* a Git feature, where you basically send someone a patch and ask them to approve and apply it.

Answer (score 1):

A “pull request” in the widest sense of the term is a request to pull some
changes from somehwere. You can do that by:

- Sending an email with a link to your publicly available repository
- Forking a project on GitHub and making a *GitHub Pull Request*
- Giving someone a thumbdrive with the repository on
- Making a new branch in a Bitbucket repository (shared by everyone) and
  then making a pull request against the main branch (maybe called `main`)

And so on, *ad infinitum*.

It’s really just a gesture: please take these changes from here and put
them where your repository is. (It could also be the same repository.)

So there is definitely a way to process pull requests in an offline
environment. You could make a branch on this shared repository and then
ask someone if it is okay to merge it. That’s a pull request.

A pull request has got nothing to do with the Internet (offline),
inherently.

I could choose to be a person who never leaves the house without wearing a
vanity t-shirt. That could be a choice that I made. But I would be wrong
if I convinced myself that vanity t-shirts are the only kind of (very
specific) upper-body garment that a person could wear. Likewise, it is
wrong to conflate *pull requests* with details like GitHub or being
Online.